# Method based on Combobox index at load

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, form-load

I'm creating a method to manage Buttons positions in my app, C# / VS2019. Basically, when I launch the app it should search for the settings file to read various settings and, with these, a setting that states the position of some Buttons. To put it simply, this setting is about aligning Buttons like you would do in a text (but instead of words in the rows I have Buttons on the Form).

The method already exists and normally you would use a Combobox to set the property (and then it goes also stored in the settings file, so that if you relaunch the app it's already set). If I use the Combobox it works well. When instead I launch the app, despite the value being read and correct, and also the Combobox selecting the right index, the Buttons won't move at all.

I also have a similar method for the app language and it works. These are the examples of the 2:

```
//TO CHANGE THE LANGUAGE IN FORM LOAD, SEARCH "Lingua:000" OR 001, righe IS string[] STORING ANY TEXT LINE OF THE FILE
                for (int lindove = 0; lindove < righe.Length; lindove++)
                {
                    string setlin = righe[lindove];
                    if (setlin.Contains("Lingua:") && setlin.Length == 10)
                    {
                        string cifre = "0123456789", contr = setlin.Substring(7, 3);
                        bool linguaok = true;
                        //CHECK WITHOUT ANY DOUBT contr IS AN INT NUMBER (0-9)
                        for (int i = 0; i < contr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (cifre.IndexOf(contr.Substring(i, 1)) == -1)
                            {
                                linguaok = false;
                            }
                        }
                        //IF IT IS INDEED INT NUMBER, LANG. COMBOBOX SET AND CHANGES LANGUAGE
                        if (linguaok == true)
                        {
                            if (Int32.Parse(contr) < lingue.Length) //lingue IS AN ARRAY OF LANGUAGES
                            {
                                linguacombo.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(contr);
                            }
                            else { MessageBox.Show(BASICALLY, ERROR); caricalingua(0); }
                        }
                        else { MessageBox.Show(BASICALLY, ERROR); caricalingua(0); }
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

`caricalingua` is a method to change language based on that int value. 0 means it calls default language. Down below I'll explain what it does in a simple way, to compare the 2 things. This, instead, is the alignment part, right after the part above (always in Form_Load)

```
//TO CHANGE ALIGNMENT IN FORM LOAD, SEARCH "Allineamento:0" OR 1/2/3/4, righe IS string[] STORING ANY TEXT LINE OF THE FILE
                for (int alldove = 0; alldove < righe.Length; alldove++)
                {
                    string setall = righe[alldove];
                    if (setall.Contains("Allineamento:") && setall.Length == 14)
                    {
                        string cifre = "01234", contr = setall.Substring(13, 1);
                        //IF THE CHAR FOUND IS A NUMBER IN cifre, GO TO COMBOBOX INDEX contr
                        if (cifre.Contains(contr))
                        {
                            allineamenti.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(contr);
                        }
                        else { MessageBox.Show(BASICALLY, ERROR); allineametodo(0); }
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

`allineametodo` is a method to align the buttons based on the Combobox index. 0 means it calls default alignment. Now, the difference between this and `caricalingua` is only the fact that the first only changes positions of the Buttons, the latter instead mainly changes text in Buttons and Labels but ALSO changes positions of some controls due to the change of words.

I tried calling directly the method from the Form_Load, didn't work. As you see I just set the index for the Combobox, didn't work. I tried reverting the two (maybe works only the first, stupid attempt, but who knows?) and same result. The problem is that, as I said, it actually changes index, but with no moving for the Buttons, and also as I said if I call those two methods by manually selecting the Comboboxes or by another way (like a Button that states to select an index), it does work. At first I thought it was because I'm trying to change some positions at Load but then realised that also the other method does it and it DOES work and I have already done it in the past, so I don't think the Form_Load is the matter (I also tried to refresh Form and Buttons). Do you have any ideas about this? I know that there are other ways around to fix this, but I'd rather keep it like this and understand why the language works and the alignment doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

### Order of showing a form:

- Control HandleCreated
- Control BindingContextChanged
- Form Load
- Control VisibleChanged
- Form Activated
- Form Shown

The Form _Load event takes place before visible changed, activated and shown. It is probable that the settings changes you make get overwritten during those events.

Try overriding the Form.Shown event and make the position changes there and see if it works correctly. If it does look at code that might override in Activated and VisibleChanged.